# Is it possible to remove Blogger attribution from default mobile version?

Tags: mobile, default, blogger, blogspot

I know how to remove Blogger attribution from custom mobile version of blogspot blog. But is it possible to remove Blogger attribution from default mobile version? If possible, how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. That is the main reason why Custom Mobile templates exist (Refer to https://blogger-developers.googleblog.com/2011/11/introducing-custom-mobile-templates.html)

In case, you don't want to switch to custom mobile templates, then there is a workaround possible which will hide the Blogger attribution from post pages and static pages. But it requires manually adding the following CSS to each post/static page's content -

```
<style>.Attribution{display:none}</style>
```

You can utilize the **Post Template** functionality present in Settings > Posts, comments and sharing > Posts to automate this for new posts